# How do I format dates on the x-axis of a chart?

Tags: vb.net, datetime, charts

I have written the following VB.NET code which plots standard scores as a function of date and time on a Windows form.

```
Public Sub PopulateChart(ByVal PairId As Integer, ByVal SymbolA As String, ByVal SymbolB As String)
    Dim DateTimes As List(Of DateTime)
    Dim StandardScores As List(Of Double)
    Me.Visible = True
    Me.BringToFront()
    Me.Text = SymbolA & " " & SymbolB
    graStandardScores.Series("StandardScores").Points.Clear()
    DateTimes = GetStandardScoreDates(PairId)
    StandardScores = GetStandardScores(PairId)
    For i = 0 To StandardScores.Count - 1
        If Double.IsInfinity(StandardScores(i)) = False Then
            graStandardScores.Series("StandardScores").Points.AddXY(DateTimes(i), StandardScores(i))
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Each point is thirty seconds apart and the data span multiple days.  I would like only one label for each day to be displayed on the x-axis, but also a label for each hour of the day.  What is the best way to accomplish this?